# Using interface as a field with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I can't seem to find a way to use interfaces instead of concrete classes in fields with Hibernate. Now, i know it's not really how relational databases are supposed to work with plain tables, but i need something like this:

```
public class Pojo{
    @Column
    field1;

    @Column
    field2;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "field_pojo", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "pojo_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "field3_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
    Field3 field3;

    setField1;
    getField1();

    setField2();
    getField2();

    setField3();
    getField3();
}

interface Field3{
    setField();
    getField();
}

class FieldImp implements Field3 {
    field;
    pojo;

    setField();
    getField();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "fieldimp")
    getPojo();
    setPojo();
}

class DiffFieldImp implements Field3 {
    field;
    field1;

    setField();
    getField();

    setField1();
    getField1();
}
```

If i just use `FieldImp fieldImp` it would work with a bit of `@DiscriminatorColumn` magic, but with an interface Hibernate looks for annotated Field3 interface.

The idea is that, for example, i have an Authenticator pojo, with `LdapAuthenticator authenticator` field to store a link on auth object.
However, there can be other types of authenticators, and it would be of use to be able to have a field `Authenticator authenticator` to handle Ldap, OpenId or any other future authenticators.

All i managed to find on this was `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)`, but it only seems to work with abstract classes and even then doesn't help when abstract class is used as a field.

Most recent Hibernate Docs suggest that @AnyToOne and @OneToAny are usable with interfaces, but i guess i need @AnyToAny, and there's just no info on that one anywhere...

Comment: Have you tried table per subclass startegy . This will support polymorphic association

Comment: Yeah, that's what i did initially. Either i implemented it wrong, or it doesn't work with interfaces (some articles on the internet indicate that annotation based approach doesn't work with inheritance).

Comment: You might have done it wrong .. It certainly works ... Please post you mapping with table per subclass strategy ..

Comment: I used a simpler approached - rearranged my data in such a way, that a simpler One To One relation between the tables is all i need now. Thanks for your help.